# Bergman's Diamond Lemma: do these rules lead to a normal form?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, rewriting-systems

Last week I was recommended Bergman's Diamond Lemma in these [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133212/does-yx-x2y-admit-a-normal-form). I read through the paper, and was working on [an exercise in it on page 193](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82189264.pdf#page=16):

> Examine for termination each of the following singleton
>   reduction-systems on $\mathbf{k}\langle x, y \rangle$: $\{(x^2y, yx)\}$, $\{(yx, x^2y)\}$, $\{(x^2y^2, yx)\}$, $\{(yx, x^2y^2)\}$.

I want to know if the reduction systems $\{(x^2y^2,yx)\}$ and $\{(yx,x^2y^2)\}$ lead to a normal form.

- The rule $(x^2y^2,yx)$ is length reducing and has no overlap ambiguities, and so $(x^2y^2,yx)$ leads to a normal form.
- On the other hand, the rule $(yx,x^2y^2)$ has no overlaps. In this case, consider the term $y^2x$. Under this reduction, we have the series of reductions
  \begin{gather*}
  y^2x \\ yx^2y^2 \\ x^2y^2xy^2\\ x^2yx^2y^2y^2\\ x^2x^2y^2xy^4\\ x^4yx^2y^2y^4\\ x^4yx^2y^6\\ x^4x^2y^2xy^6\\\vdots
  \end{gather*}
  and evidently this term does not reduce to a normal form as there is always some $x$ to the right of some $y$ after performing a reduction.

Did I understand these correctly? I wasn't sure about the second case, since I felt lucky that I chose such a monomial to reduce.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you're right. And it's not just a lucky guess of word $y^2x$; it's the perfect example of a word that's not reduction-finite, so you know that the rule $\{(yx,x^2y^2)\}$ won't terminate for every word in $\mathbf{k}\langle x,y \rangle$, and so that rule doesn't give you a normal form. All you need is that one counterexample. :)